# Paramiko exec_command hangs on docker exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, apache-spark, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to test docker commands from an external system (I need to do this I can't just build the container and test it locally) and the test case that I am trying to run involves starting up Apache Spark and running one of the examples, specifically SparkPi. For some reason my python script hangs on the `docker exec ...` command below. However, previously perform other docker execs and have not had a problem running everything manually. It only breaks when I put everything in the script.

**Command**:

```py
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(f'docker exec {spark_container_id} bash -c \'"$SPARK_HOME"/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
                --master spark://$(hostname):7077 "$SPARK_HOME"/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.1.jar {self.slices_to_calculate}\'')
print("\nstdout is:\n" + stdout.read() + "\nstderr is:\n" + stderr.read())
```

Any idea what could be causing this? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the reason for this is because I didn't have the `get_pty=True` parameter for `exec_command`. It must be the case that by attaching a terminal to the `spark-submit` command the output gets printed properly. So the solution to this would be

```py
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(f'docker exec -t {spark_container_id} bash -c \'"$SPARK_HOME"/bin/spark-submit ...', get_pty=True)
```

**NOTE**: By using `get_pty=True` the `stdout` and `stderr` of the `exec_command` get combined.